# How to get date from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I want to get date from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL.
Example: I have two parameter `@startdate : 2015-12-28` and `@enddate : 2016-01-02`, and database in SQLServer, datatype is varchar(10)

```
DATE_ORDER
28-12-2015
30-12-1996
29-12-2016
30-12-1997
24-12-2015
27-12-1993
03-01-2016
01-01-1992
02-01-2016
etc...
```

Ok,now I want to get data from `@startdate : 2015-12-28` and `@enddate : 2016-01-02`. I use `SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE DATE_ORDER >= @startdate AND DATE_ORDER <= @enddate` . But the results are not what I expected. Here are the results I want

```
28-12-2015
30-12-1996
29-12-2016
30-12-1997
01-01-1992
02-01-2016
```

[image]

I think to solve this problem, I need to do two things :
First, get date range from `@startdate` to `@enddate` , in here `28/12/2015, 29/12/2015, 30/12/2015, 31/12/2015, 01/01/2016, 02/01/2016`. 
The second: get the date in database same in range `28/12, 29/12, 30/12, 31/12, 01/01, 02/01`, ignoring the year.
Can you give me some ideas about this ?

Comment: Dates are datatypes / structures, they are not strings and also Sql Server applies no formatting to them. Applying formatting to a non-string structure implies converting that structure to a string. This should happen as late as possible in the application/program stack, usually in the presentation layer. As such there are no good ways to apply formatting to dates/times in Sql Server, because it does not belong there.

Comment: I update the question, plz check it, thank you

Comment: Again, The best solution is to convert your schema so that the dates are of actual sql type `Date` or `DateTime2`, not varchar. If you have control of the schema, change it. If you do not try to convince who ever does that this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual format is "105-italian" [find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

You can convert your existing `VARCHAR(10)`-values with this line to *real datetime*

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,YourColumn,105)
```

Next thing to know is, that you should not use `BETWEEN` but rather `>=StartDate AND < NakedDateOfTheFollowingDay` to check date ranges

So to solve your need *Get date-range from 2015-12-28 to 2016-01-02* you might do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME={d'2015-12-28'};
DECLARE @End DATETIME={d'2016-01-02'};

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,YourDateColumn,105)>=@Start AND CONVERT(DATETIME,YourDateColumn,105)<@End+1
```

**Attention** Be aware, that the conversion lets your expression be **not sargable**. No index will be used.

#### Better was to store your date as correctly typed data to avoid conversions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @wk int SET @wk = 2
DECLARE @yr int SET @yr = 2011

--define start and end limits

DECLARE @todate datetime, @fromdate datetime
SELECT @fromdate = dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (YEAR, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
         datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (YEAR, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
SELECT @todate = @fromdate + 6

;WITH DateSequence( Date ) AS
(
    SELECT @fromdate AS Date
        UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(DAY, 1, Date)
        FROM DateSequence
        WHERE Date < @todate
)

--select result
SELECT * FROM DateSequence OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after the 2nd or 3rd edit, it slowly becomes clear, what you want (i hope).

So you REALLY WANT to get the dates with the year beeing ignored.

As someone pointed out already, date-values are stored internally not as string, but as internal datatype date (whatever that is in memory, i don't know).

If you want to compare DATES, you cannot do that with ignorance of any part. If you want to, you have to build a NEW date value of day and month of given row and a hard coded year (2000 or 1 or whatever) for EVERY row.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE convert(date,'2000' + substring(convert(char(8),convert(datetime, 'DATE_ORDER', 105),112),5,4),112) >= @startdate AND convert(date,'2000' + substring(convert(char(8),convert(datetime, 'DATE_ORDER', 105),112),5,4),112) <= @enddate
```

If your startdate and enddate go OVER sylvester, you have to do 2 queries, on from startdate to 1231, one from 0101 to enddate.